# Problem with Binary Search tree code for insert operation

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am unable to access the left,right nodes from my root node in my insert function as evidenced by the terminal output. What is causing the error.

Code Body:

```
#include<iostream>

class Node {
    public:
    int key; int data;
    Node * left;
    Node* right;
    Node (int key, int data):key(key),data(data),right(nullptr),left(nullptr){std::cout<<"ooga booga"<<std::endl;}

    //Recursive function to insert an key into BST
    void insert( int key,int data)
    {
        std::cout<<"reached here.Current node now has key="<<this->key<<" while input key is "<<key <<std::endl;
        // if the root is null, create a new node an return it
        if (this == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout<<"in 1st if block "<<this->key<<std::endl;    
            this->key=key;
            this->data=data;
            return;
        }

        // if given key is less than the root node, recur for left subtree
        if (key < this->key)
        {   
            std::cout<<"in 2nd if block "<<this->key<<std::endl;    
            left->insert(key, data);
            std::cout<<"in else block 2"<<this->key<<std::endl;
        }

        // if given key is more than the root node, recur for right subtree
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"in else block "<<this->key<<std::endl;  
            right->insert(key, data);}
            std::cout<<"in else block 2"<<this->key<<std::endl; 
            return;
        }

// A utility function to do inorder traversal of BST 
void inorder() 
{ 
    if (this != nullptr) 
    { 
        this->left->inorder(); 
        printf("%d \n", this->key); 
        this->right->inorder(); 
    } 
} 



};


// Driver Program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    /* Let us create following BST 
              50 
           /     \ 
          30      70 
         /  \    /  \ 
       20   40  60   80 */
    Node *root=new Node(50,10); 
    std::cout<<root<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<root->left<<std::endl;
    //root=nullptr;
    std::cout<<"reached here"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"reached here.Root now has key="<<root->key<<std::endl;
    root->insert( 0,10); 
    root->insert( 20,10); 
    root->insert( 40,10); 
    root->insert( 70,10); 
    root->insert(  60,10); 
    root->insert( 80,10); 
    std::cout<<"reached here 2"<<std::endl;
    // print inoder traversal of the BST 
    root->inorder(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
ooga booga
0x7fffc10c6e70
0
reached here
reached here.Root now has key=50
reached here.Current node now has key=50 while input key is 0
in 2nd if block 50
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: after checking that `this` is a `nullptr`, why do you immediately then try to access its data member `this->key`? You just checked that it is `nullptr`. `this->key` doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, that was jus an extra debug statement  I put in to see how deep the program run before encountering the segmentation fault.

Comment: Try your code on a single node tree.  You will probably see it doesn't work either, which means you really didn't test your tree on the simplest of cases (a single node).

Comment: after initializing each `Node` object with `left=nullptr` and `right=nullptr`, why do you then try to access `left->insert`? left is `nullptr`. `nullptr` does not have a `left` member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General summary:

You are creating `Node` objects with `left=nullptr` and `right=nullptr`.

You are never actually initializing these `left` and `right` pointers to a `new Node`.

Before trying to access `left->insert`, you must first create a `new Node`.

Comment: yes that was the root cause. As  nullptr, left did not have any identity as being a node* pointer. Thus the compiler could not properly allocate the insert () function to it

Answer (score 0):

So this is the only change made to the insert function based on MPops reply which now works:

```
void insert( int key,int data)
{
    if (key < this->key) {
        if(this->left ==nullptr)
            { left=new Node(key,data); return;}
        else 
            left->insert(key,data);
    }

    else {
        if(this->right ==nullptr)
            { right=new Node(key,data); return;}
        else 
            right->insert(key,data);
    }


}
```